# Deploying python flask app to Azure web app using azure pipelines. Getting default page only

Tags: azure, azure-devops, build, yaml

I'm trying to deploy a flask app to azure web app using Azure DevOps pipeline.
The pipeline is successful but instead of getting the application home page I get the default web app home page.
default page :
[defaultimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaEoY.png)

I am following this link by Microsoft :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python-webapp?view=azure-devops
I am also using the same repository that they have created for basic flask tutorial deployment.(https://github.com/Microsoft/python-sample-vscode-flask-tutorial)

My yaml file looks like this :

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: 'Deploy Stage'
    jobs:
      - job: DeploymentJob
        displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        steps:
        - task: UsePythonVersion@0
          inputs:
              versionSpec: '3.9'
          displayName: 'Use Python 3.9'

        - script: |
              python -m venv antenv
              source antenv/bin/activate
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              pip install setup
              pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
          workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
          displayName: "Install requirements"

        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          inputs:
            rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
            includeRootFolder: false
            archiveType: 'zip'
            archiveFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
            replaceExistingArchive: true
        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          inputs:
            targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            artifactName: 'drop'
            publishLocation: 'pipeline'
          
        - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            buildType: 'current'
            downloadType: 'single'
            artifactName: 'drop'
            downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
        
        - task: AzureWebApp@1
          inputs:
            appType : 'webApp'
            azureSubscription: 'azure-cloud-exampele'
            appName: 'xyz'
            package: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
            startUpCommand: 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --workers=4 startup:app'
```

I have made some changes to the original yaml file mentioned on the website. This is because it gave multiple errors and the build was failing everytime.
Could someone please tell me why it is not able to display my flask home page? Have been stuck on this for the past 3 days :(

Answer (score 1):

While trying to reproduce the same with your code, I have identified an issue with the **PublishPipelineArtifact@1** step and **AzureWebApp@1** step.

The code was archiving the file in a different location (PublishPipelineArtifact@1) but publishing a different folder ($(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)). As a result, even though the pipeline was successful, it wasn't actually producing any artifacts.

I have modifed your pipeline code as below and now it is working as expected.

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: 'Deploy Stage'
    jobs:
      - job: DeploymentJob
        displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        steps:
        - task: UsePythonVersion@0
          inputs:
              versionSpec: '3.9'
          displayName: 'Use Python 3.9'

        - script: |
              python -m venv antenv
              source antenv/bin/activate
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              pip install setup
              pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
          workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
          displayName: "Install requirements"

        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          inputs:
            rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
            includeRootFolder: false
            archiveType: 'zip'
            archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
            replaceExistingArchive: true
        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          inputs:
            targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            artifactName: 'drop'
            publishLocation: 'pipeline'
          
        - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            buildType: 'current'
            downloadType: 'single'
            artifactName: 'drop'
            downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
        
        - task: AzureWebApp@1
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: 'spnv-g'
            appType: 'webAppLinux'
            appName: 'helloworld-flaskpipelines'
            deployToSlotOrASE: true
            resourceGroupName: 'rg_4099'
            package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
            startUpCommand: 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --workers=4 startup:app'
```

I made changes to the 'ArchiveFiles' task and 'AzureWebApp' task as shown in the provided screenshots:

[changes made in archievefile task](https://i.imgur.com/XcHsOWL.png)

[changes made in azurewebapp task](https://i.imgur.com/LW3SkfM.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]